# value from ajax jquery json call in input hidden

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I get `data.my_id` from an AJAX call. I want to place it inside a hidden input named `my_id`, but I am not able to do it. Is there a special way to succeed with this sort of input? Is it normal not to see the AJAX return in the sources of the page? Thanks and sorry for my school English.

```js
// dat.my_id is working in an alert
$(#my_id).html(data.my_id);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="my_id" id="my_id" value="<?= $my_id; ?>" />
```

Comment: try $(#my_id).val(data.my_id);

Comment: you could hide your input through css, using:  display:none;

Comment: @krisph you can do it olso with css but he didn't ask how to hide it, he ask how to pass the value ;)

Comment: Just a suggestion really

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep value of hidden empty initially.

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_id" id="my_id" value="" />
```

Then on ajax response you can set the value as below:

```
$("#my_id").val(data.my_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a value to your input you can use

```
$('#my_id').val(data.my_id);
```

Some [examples](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp)

Comment: Not working. 
nothing in the sources show me i retrieve the data.

Comment: I've change to test hidden with text  and data is not there.

Comment: try passing the values manualy. On your browser open inspect element end go to console. After going to console try $('#my_id').val("test"); does the value changes?

Comment: uncaught type error   my_id isn"t a function  (message on console) but to test i've changed my input hidden in input text  perhaps it's why. Sorry for my english

Comment: it's ok dont worry what have you typed on console?

Comment: $('#my_id').val("test");

Comment: hmm have you try to remove the first value from the input as @Samir suggested?

Comment: I've find the reason : it'because normally i've the code before my html for the inputs :  $my_id=!empty($_POST['my_id'])?$_POST['my_id']:''; When I put it in  comment it's working. But is it normal nothing on page sources ?

Comment: i could not understand the question, If you have problems with the code add it to the question and we will take a look :)

Comment: It's working in the browser but nothing in souces of the page .... Is it normal ? cause I need further this variable to make a request.

Comment: aa ok now i understand. So we can pass the value but the code does not pass it. Please post your complity code to the question to take a look at

Comment: Thank a lot for your interest. You've the code .. Just code a numeric value to data.my.id to be able to test.